# scene data export with .flushToDom, problems with "event attributes" data

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm writing script for send scene data to server. 
To evade attribute parsing, i using

> .flushToDom()

and here is one problem. 
He have parsed some attribute's data like a string "[Object object]"

.
[image]

Ok. I have var where is stored scene. I'm trying to change events data manualy:

```
 document.querySelector('a-scene').flushToDOM(true);
 var cursor = scene.getElementsByTagName('a-cursor')[0];

 //console: [object Object]
 console.log(cursor.getAttribute('event-set__1'));
 cursor.setAttribute('event-set__1','_event: mouseenter; color: springgreen');

 //console: undefined    
 console.log(cursor.getAttribute('event-set__1'));
 cursor.setAttribute('event-set__2','_event: mouseleave; color: black');
```

but, it doesn't help. So, how can i set event's data without her activation?

> UPDATED after **Piotr Adam Milewski** comment

to save attributes data, we need to clone node before .flushToDom(),
then we can modify attributes.

```
var cursor = document.getElementsByTagName('a-cursor')[0];
var cursorClone = cursor.cloneNode(true);
var cursorParent = cursor.parentNode;

document.querySelector('a-scene').flushToDOM(true);

cursorClone.setAttribute("event-set__1", {"_event": "mouseenter", "material.color": "springgreen"});
cursorClone.setAttribute("event-set__2", {"_event": "mouseleave", "material.color": "black"});

cursorParent.removeChild(cursor);
cursorParent.appendChild(cursorClone);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
cursor.setAttribute('event-set__2','_event: mouseleave; color: black');
```

try

```
this.el.setAttribute("event-set__2", {
    "_event": "mouseenter",
    "material.color": "red"
})
```

It should be [working](https://jsfiddle.net/hL75zwts/10/)